# Cannot view crystal Report in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a simple application that shows table data. I am using `CrystalReportViewer` and the code behind on `PageLoad` event is as follows:

```
        SqlConnection con;
        string connString = null;
        connString = "Data Source=.;initial catalog=InvoiceSystem;user id=sa;password=rfm";
        con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        con.Open();

        string query = null;
        query = "Select * from tblInvoice";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        con.Close();


        DataSetInv ds = new DataSetInv();
        da.Fill(ds, "tblInvoice");

        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReportInv.rpt"));
        rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```

Problem is when I run my application, the browser is blank. It is not rendering the report.Some tutorials suggested to browse using IISM but when I do I get error:

> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

What am I missing?

Comment: The error is self explanatory isn't it

Comment: But the resource is there. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReportInv.rpt")); what path is this? Can you hard code a path to test?